# Get current audio sessions Android Java - Equalizer

Tags: java, android, audio

i am making a Equalizer app for Android. The problem is that the audio session id 0 global is obsolete.
other apps, use a "compatibility mode" to solve this.
in it you can choose an active audio session and equalize it.
I put example images.
Thanks.
Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: App example]

[image: App example]

[image: App example]

Comment: [`MediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)) maybe?

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? If yes, could you please share?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984951/1593550